# getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) doesnt work in custom view

Tags: java, android, android-handler, android-viewgroup

I built a custom view, and in its constructor i do `postDelay()` to use glide to update a imageview

```
postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Glide.with(getContext())
            .load("url").asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
                    setBackground(drawable);
                }
            });
        }
    },5000);
```

and in case that user click back and activity got destroyed so Glide will crash the app(Glide check whether the activity still valid or not)
I will clean all the message in handler.

so in the `onDetachedFromWindow()` method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        getHandler().removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
```

But the problem is the runnable which I `postDelay()` still got fired even if I quickly click back button( 1 -2 sec).

Is there any reason why?

THanks

Comment: Just use [Glide.clear()](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/331/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#clear(android.view.View)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources of `View#postDelayed` :

```
public boolean  postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis) {  
    final AttachInfo attachInfo = mAttachInfo;

    if (attachInfo != null) {
        return attachInfo.mHandler.postDelayed(action, delayMillis);
    }

    // Assume that post will succeed later
    ViewRootImpl.getRunQueue().postDelayed(action, delayMillis);
    return true;
}
```

This `AttachInfo` is assigned on `dispatchAttachedToWindow` which is happening after the constructor. This mean that on constructor task is assigned to the `ViewRoot` run queue. And on  `onDetachedFromWindow` you are simply trying to to remove from wrong queue.

The solution - simply move this `postDelayed` call to `onAttachedToWindow()`